# Upgraded to React Native 0.60.5, but my ios folder doesn't have Podfile

Tags: react-native

I recently upgraded my react native project from 0.59 to 0.60.5, however I wasn't using pods from the earlier version. How do I generate the Podfile for 0.60.5 to apply the new update?

Comment: have you tried to install pod with brew?

Comment: Have you opened the. Xcoworkspace extension in xcode ++?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this [resource](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.0&to=0.60.5). In the embedded link, I have selected your previous version of React Native and the new version you're upgrading to. I hope this helps you.